# Error: Problem: nothing provides /usr/libexec/platform-python needed by mongodb-org-database-tools-extra-4.4.5-1.el8.x86_64

Tags: python, linux, mongodb, fedora

I am using Fedora Linux and when i want to update MongoDB tools (mongodb-org-tools) or my packages via `sudo dnf update`
i always get error like this:

```
Error: 
 Problem: problem with installed package mongodb-org-database-tools-extra-4.4.4-1.el8.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package mongodb-org-database-tools-extra-4.4.4-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides /usr/libexec/platform-python needed by mongodb-org-database-tools-extra-4.4.5-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides /usr/libexec/platform-python needed by mongodb-org-database-tools-extra-4.4.6-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides /usr/libexec/platform-python needed by mongodb-org-database-tools-extra-4.4.7-1.el8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

i had similar error for updating mongodb and i solved them by `sudo dnf upgrade mongodb-org-mongos --best --allowerasing`.
but still i have problem with mongodb tools

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also had problems installing Mongodb on Fedora 33. These problems occurred when I had the following code in /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org.repo :

```
[Mongodb]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/8/mongodb-org/4.4/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc
```

But if I use this repository instead (i.e. replace the above code in /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org.repo with the code below), it all works fine:

```
[Mongodb]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2013.03/mongodb-org/4.4/x86_64
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc
```

Next install mongodb:

```
sudo dnf install mongodb-org
```

Start the service:

```
sudo service start mongod
```

After starting the service as above, you can then use the usual systemctl commands to stop, start and show status of the service. The above command to start the service is needed only once.

```
sudo systemctl stop mongod
sudo systemctl start mongod
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

Further note on Fedora 34:

The above does not work on Fedora 34 as mongodb-org-shell dependencies on an older version of openssl causes problems:

```
- nothing provides libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.0-1.amzn1.x86_64
- nothing provides libssl.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.4.0-1.amzn1.x86_64
```

I conclude from https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-58870 that
the Mongodb team do not plan to support their product on Fedora going forward, as Mongodb 5.0 is also not supported on Fedora 34, although a workaround is suggested. I'm therefore going to consider other NoSQL options.

Answer (score 8):

My solution was to use MongoDB for Amazon Linux and use copr to satisfy the libcrypto and libssl dependencies

```
dnf copr enable dioni21/compat-openssl10
```

In my case I used it to install MongoDB 5.0 on Fedora 36 using
these instructions:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/

Comment: Thank you for this! I had all sorts of issues trying to figure this out. This solved the issue I was looking to do mongo with Fedora 36 as well.

Comment: thanks for this as well, how did you know to enable copr?